# Filter data with start & end date in intervals (months, weeks)

Tags: dax, data-modeling, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to build a data-analysis table (in PowerBi if that matters) that shows sum of task hours per resource (row) and date-window (column).
I.e getting a result as ...

| Resource | Month 1 | Month 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 40h | 30h |
| BB | 20h | 10h |

My data however is structured in a way that I have one data point per resource/task combination without breaking down the date. I.e. the data is structured like ...

| Resource | Task | Hours | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | XX | 10h | 10.10.22 | 01.02.23 |
| AB | XZ | 5h | 01.11.22 | 05.11.22 |

So i need to sum all tasks per resource but also break them down to how many hours per month. Ideally i can also switch to weeks view in my dashboard.

How can I best achieve this?
Transform the data? Some special filter?

Any Tips or pointers to tutorials ecc. would be great. Thanks.

Best

Comment: And how do you split time per month/Week/Day? Hours / Daysbetween Start and End?
You should consider simplifing your model in a way you don't need the Start and End, one row per day with the amount you want.

Comment: Hi @mxix and thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately I have no control over the raw data itself (i can transfrom it though). The datasource is Dynamics 365 Project Service Operations. For some reason unknown they store data in that model.

Splitting time could be just simply an even distribution, meaning that I just do "Total hours"/ "Date-Difference" to get the hours per day. Actually I am able to compute that value in a simply calculated column. 

I do struggle however to then put that into a week / month / whatever time frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can store a lot of data, you should do something like this:

1. calculate hours per date for every *Resource-Task* group (this can be done inside original table);
2. create a new calendar table (one column with dates) and cross-join it with distinct *Resources*;
3. add a column to newly created table where you will calculate sum of hours per this date and *Resource*;
4. use this analytical table for your purposes grouping data by necessary periods.

Comment: Hi and thanks. This might work. The idea with an new calendar table is appealing as I could also use this to only use work days (no weekends etc.).
I'll try it ...